# Laptop's keyboard is not working

Tags: keyboard

I'm just finishing installing Elementary OS but I got a problem. Really, the problem was not on this installation, but it was on Linux Mint 20 update. I was running Linux Mint 20 and I got some system updates. When restarting, my laptop's keyboard is no working any longer. I tried with an external keyboard and it works ok. I assumed that it is a Linux Mint problem and I tried with Zorin OS and finally with Elementary OS. The result is the same: Laptop's keyboard is not working. Any idea about what's going on? I don't want to use an external keyboard. Hope somebody can help on this. Thank you very much. You all have a nice day.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I just had this occur on my ElementaryOS when I ran an update. I tried a fresh install of ElementaryOS and it's still the same problem. Dualboot Windows has no problems with keyboard, neither does BIOS. External keyboard works fine. I tried install xserver-xorg-input-all and it hasn't fixed it either.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve my issue with this by going back to an old kernel version. Have you tried that at all?